# how to set axis in matplotlib not equal?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following figure in `matplotlib`. What i want to do is to have the scale of z-axis proportional to x-y-axis.

[image: matplotlib figure]

and achieve something like this:

[image: original figure]

Comment: Did you try setting the `zlim` to a larger range?

Comment: no i have not modified zlim

Comment: See [similar questions](https://www.google.de/search?q=matplotlib+equal+aspect+3d+site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @Bazingaa by adding zlim it works. however i don't know if there is an alternative way

Comment: If you read through some of the question I linked you to you will find that you may monkey-patch the 3d axes with what people call `pbaspect` to achieve a true change in aspect ratio for 3D plots.

Answer (score 0):

adding the following works:

```
ax.set_zlim(-1, 1)
```

[correct figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Myp.png)

however i wonder if there is an alternative way!

Answer (score -1):

There is more than one way you can do that;

Approach 1:

Setting the axis limit:

```
plt.zlim(tuple)
```

where

```
tuple = (z0,zf)
```

another way:

```
plt.zticks(array_1, array_2)
```

where

```
array_1 := range
array_2 := labels
```

Hope it helps!